# Proof by induction, inductive step problem

Tags: proof-explanation

Prove by induction:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i =\frac {1}{2} (3^{n+1}-1)$$

Now, i know how to do the first step and i understand it but then i have a problem with the second step which is showing that its true for n+1.

My question is:

Is this notation corect:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} 3^i =\frac {1}{2} (3^{n+2}-1)$$
Which of these is corect and why?
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} 3^i =\sum_{i=0}^{n} 3^i+n+1$$
or
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} 3^i =\sum_{i=0}^{n} 3^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those is correct, but the first one is closer. What you want to say is
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}3^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}3^{i}+3^{n+1}$$
since $3^{n+1}$ is the extra term missing from the sum on the right hand side. To complete the proof, the induction hypothesis implies that the right hand side is
$$\frac{1}{2}(3^{n+1}-1)+3^{n+1}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot3^{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 3^{n+2}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n+2}-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Notation looks good.

Your base case is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^0{3^i}=3^0=1$$
$$\frac12(3^1-1)=\frac12(2)=1$$
so true for $n=0$

Inductive Step:

Assume the statement true for $n=k$, that is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^k{3^i}=\frac12(3^{k+1}-1)$$
Then show for $n=k+1$. We use that:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}{3^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}{3^i}+3^{k+1}$$
This is the correct expansion of that sum as opposed to what you suggested. We achieve this by finding the $(k+1)$th term of the sum and adding it to the summation to $k$ terms.

So you need to show that:

$$\frac12(3^{k+1}-1)+3^{k+1}=\frac12(3^{k+2}-1)$$